# User dynamic variables in whatsapp templates provided by facebook

Tags: java, facebook, web, communication, whatsapp

I want to generate a whatsapp template using dynamic variables. 
The same thing can be done in email easily as it supports for loops, but whatsapp template doesn't support this.

As an example I want to achieve this:

```
a-10
b-20
c-30
```

The number of elements can vary.

For email I will pass a list of values for a variable. The variables in the code should be filled with character and value and be accessed in a template like this:

```
{{variable_name}}
  {{character}} - {{value}}
{{variable_name}}
```

It should produce the result as shown in the description above.

**How to do the same thing in whatsapp?**

Comment: Are you talking about the WhatsApp Business API? The documentation for that has a section titled Message Templates, which explains this …

Comment: please complete your example - especially show the for loop and name the e-mail solution you are using. Please also show what you found out yourself so far about the options of whatsapp

Comment: I have found out that watsapp doesn't support loops.